# Magento looking at base before custom theme

Tags: css, magento, themes, magento-1.7

I bought a theme for Magento and changed some css. Recently the theme updated to the new my_theme/default file path (it used to be using the default/my_theme). I am trying to create a custom theme so that when I update the theme it won't interfere with my custom changes.

I set the current package name to "my_theme" and set default (under Design/Themes) to custom_theme. And saved everything. I also disabled and flushed all the caches. It still reads from skin/frontend/default/my_theme/css/styles.css when it should skin/frontend/my_theme/default/css/styles.css

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 3):

FIXED IT!

The issue was not in **System > Configuration > Design** but in fact **System > Design** I discovered that **System > Design** had it set up for Default/Shopper and there wasn't a time frame for it. The following link helped me reach my conclusion.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/197908/

You are supposed to **System > Design** for temporary theme changes, but my site had it set with no time frame thus always overwriting my settings in **System > Configuration > Design**

Answer (score 0):

There is also scope configuration in back end to check to which store you have to apply your design changes

just check with upper left side drop down to effect on your magento setup to give default or your custom package.

hope this will sure help you.

Comment: I have my scope set to default configuration which means every store I have should follow what I set in my default config.

Comment: yes every store might have different setting for it's own design. just check with that.

Comment: @KevinSchaeken,if my answer is useful to you.i would be glad if you will accept and vote up. so some one can use for future reference.

Comment: Sorry @liyakat but that didn't solve the problem. See I set all the stores to use my default settings. The issue still remains that the settings I make aren't being made.